# incapacitado empezar mongod

Tags: mongodb, rutas

Buenas tardes, estoy siguendo [un curso sobre mongoDB creatado por openclassrooms](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/guide-de-demarrage-pour-utiliser-mongodb). Sin embargo despues instalarlo por http://www.mongodb.org/downloads no fue capaz utilisarlo con el commando `mongodb`. En efecto me dice que hay un `ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist.`

La salida completa esta :

```
:~/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1604-3.4.3/bin$ mongod
mongod --help for help and startup options
2017-04-06T23:24:30.258+0200 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=23743 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=antoine-Inspiron-3543
2017-04-06T23:24:30.258+0200 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.10
2017-04-06T23:24:30.258+0200 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2017-04-06T23:24:30.258+0200 [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2017-04-06T23:24:30.258+0200 [initandlisten] build info: Linux lgw01-12 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_58
2017-04-06T23:24:30.258+0200 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-04-06T23:24:30.258+0200 [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-04-06T23:24:30.258+0200 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10296 
*********************************************************************
 ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo
*********************************************************************
, terminating
2017-04-06T23:24:30.258+0200 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2017-04-06T23:24:30.258+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-04-06T23:24:30.258+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-04-06T23:24:30.258+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2017-04-06T23:24:30.258+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2017-04-06T23:24:30.258+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2017-04-06T23:24:30.259+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2017-04-06T23:24:30.259+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2017-04-06T23:24:30.259+0200 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2017-04-06T23:24:30.259+0200 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

Comment: ¿has buscado por ejemplo: `mongodb db data not exists`? he aquí una [respuesta en inglés](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24599119/4092887).

Comment: felicitaciones por lo de OpenClassroom! éxitos con el bachiller internacional :D dale con todo el power 2.0!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que crear el directorio que mongo te esta pidiendo para guardar los datos
con los siguientes comandos:

sudo mkdir -p /data/db/

sudo chown `id -u` /data/db

con el primero se crea el directorio que mongo necesita y con el segundo haces al usuario propietario del directorio para poder escribir sobre el

Comment: Muchas gracias ! dentro de `bin`?

Comment: No, solo tienes que ejecutar esos comandos para crear el directorio(la ruta es absoluta)

Comment: Querìa decir dentro de `:~/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1604-3.4.3/bin$`.
Ademas me dice : 
`sudo chown id -u /data/db
chown: invalid option -- 'u'`